# How do i add images for a specific component in a UIPickerView with several components?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipickerview

I've been trying for hours to add a `UIPickerView`with 4 components. Three of the components are supposed to show string data from three different `NSArray`'s, but for the fourth component i'm trying to add images.

In another SO-thred i read about this method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
   // return aUIView;
}
```

Which returns UIViews, which in my case would be an ImageView.

I have managed to display my imagesViews stored in my images array, but only if i were to have one component in my picker view.

How can i combine this with the other three components which are not supposed to return an UIView, but simply some string values?

This is what have i've got in my `.m` so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // Four Arrays with some data
    self.contractLevelArray = ...someStringObjects... 
    self.imageViewsWithImagesForSuitArray =...someUIImageViewObjectsWithImages...
    self.doubleOrRedoubleArray = ...someStringObjects...
    self.contractByPlayerArray = ...someStringObjects...
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if (component == 0) {
        return self.contractLevelArray.count;
    } else if (component == 1) {
        return self.imageViewsWithImagesForSuitArray.count;
    } else if (component == 2) {
        return self.contractByPlayerArray.count;
    } else {
        return self.doubleOrRedoubleArray.count;
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if (component == 0) {
        return [self.contractLevelArray objectAtIndex:row];
    } else if (component == 1) {


        // For this component i want to return the UIImageViews for my images


    } else if (component == 2) {
        return [self.contractByPlayerArray objectAtIndex:row];
    } else {
        return [self.doubleOrRedoubleArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    // self.myImages is an array of UIImageView objects
    UIView *myView = [self.imageViewsWithImagesForSuitArray objectAtIndex:row];

    // first convert to a UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.bounds.size, NO, 0);

    [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // then convert back to a UIImageView and return it
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both `viewForRow` and `titleForRow`. In your case, use just `viewForRow`.

For the image component, return image views. For the others, return labels with the needed text.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. It took me some time to figure out how to configure the labels but now it's working! :)